# No module named 'sentinelsat' / NameError: name 'SentinelAPI' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to capture the roofs of houses using SentinelAPI. I get the following error when running he following code in jupyter notebook.
No module named 'sentinelsat'

Also I tried

```
api = SentinelAPI('*username*','*password*!','https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
```

in command line and I am getting following error:

```
NameError: name 'SentinelAPI' is not defined
```

Comment: How did you import the python module ? How did you install it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command at the starting:

```
!pip install <module>
```

It is because inside jupyter library may not work. So, try using this command. This command will install the library.